# CSIDH - The inverse problem

Tags: elliptic-curves, isogeny

I started studying CSIDH a few weeks ago and, seeing these papers [[1]](https://hal.science/hal-02373179/document) [[2]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1012), I was wondering:

- Given $[a]E$ and $E$, find $[a]^{-1}E$.

I read that is easy to find $[a]^{-1}E_0$ knowing $[a]E_0$ by quadratic twisting, but I haven't found any resources explaining how to compute $[a]^{-1}E$.

So, is it possible to compute $[a]^{-1}E$ knowing $[a]E$ and $E$?

Comment: Where is the claim that it is easy from?

Comment: @Myath Sorry, my mistake. I meant that if the coefficient A is 0 in this equation: y^2 = x^3 + Ax^2 + x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In "traditional" CSIDH, where $E\colon\ y^2=x^3+x$, it always holds true that $[\mathfrak a^{-1}]E$ is the quadratic twist of $[\mathfrak a]E$.

Very concretely, if $[\mathfrak a]E$ is the Montgomery curve $E_A\colon\ y^2=x^3+Ax^2+x$, then $[\mathfrak a^{-1}]E$ is the Montgomery curve $E_{-A}\colon y^2 = x^3-Ax^2+x$.

Answer (score 2):

You are describing the inverse hard homogenous space ($\mathrm{InvHHS}$) problem (see definition 2.1.6 of your first paper) also known as the Inverse CSIDH problem (see problem 4 of your second paper). This is believed to be hard. It is analogous to the [inverse Diffie-Hellman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_assumption#Variations_of_the_Computational_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_assumption): given generator $G$ and a multiple $aG$ compute $a^{-1}G$. However, although the inverse Diffie-Hellman problem is known to be as hard as the regular computational Diffie-Hellman problem in cyclic groups of prime order, I do not know of a proof that solving $\mathrm{InvHHS}$ solves $\mathrm{CDH-HSS}$ (the reverse is true; again see the first paper) in the classical setting. There is a reduction for the in the quantum setting when the HHS is an isogeny space (see Appendix A of the second paper) where the quantum capability is used to compute the associated quadratic class group using the methods of [Sean Hallgren](https://www.cse.psu.edu/%7Esjh26/unitgroup.pdf).

Comment: So it's not possible even if $E$ is computed in a weird manner?

Comment: @OptimalNailcutter1337 Not sure that I follow you; your problem statement furnished the solver with $E$ and $[a]E$ and no additional information. Additional information could render the problem easier e.g. if you also tell the solver the value of $a$.